# excel sumproduct issue with discountinued array

Tags: excel

I am trying to sumproduct 2 arrays. My issue is that they have different size due to blank cells.
So for ex:

1 2 3 2 3 3

1 (blank) 3 2 1 (blank) 4 5

I would like to sumproduct the 2 above lines (arrays of 6). Note in my issue, there is more data, hence I dont want to manually multiply each lines. They are of different size, however if you remove the blank cells, they have the same size.
Any clue how I could go around this issue?
Many thanks

Comment: Assuming that you have limited amount of cells you could employ the formula =A1*B1*C1*D1*IF(E1="",1,E1)*F1
Where E1 is either empty or a value.
SInce your size is 6 (non empty) as long as you have something reasonable like 50 cells where 6 of them have values, you could easily write the formula or even write code that writes that formyula and use it
then you can sum the values

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(1:1,N(IF({1}, MODE.MULT(IF(C1:J1<>"", COLUMN(C1:J1)*{1;1}))))), INDEX(2:2,N(IF({1}, MODE.MULT(IF(C2:J2<>"", COLUMN(C2:J2)*{1;1}))))))`

As in the setup in the pic. It they are both columns of data instead, be sure to change the {1; 1} to {1, 1} throughout

Comment: Did this help at all?